# Simulate Gamepad button presses linux without uinput

Tags: linux, x11, gamepad, uinput

I'd like to simulate gamepad button presses in linux. I'm running in an environment without the `uinput` kernel module loaded. Could I just send X11 Events using XTEST?

Comment: Why are you trying to simulate button presses? There are multiple ways to get gamepad inputs on Linux, simulating at the X11 level may or may not work based on how the application consumes them. I think it's relatively uncommon for games to consume X11 gamepad events.

Comment: Hi @nondebug I'm running an application in a docker container that I need to simulate gamepad events for. I need to be able to programatically trigger them

Answer (score 0):

Does `xev` show all the needed events coming from your gamepad?

You could try using `xdotool` to send the events to the X server.

Comment: I'm currently using xdotool to send keyboard events and it works really well. I'll try and capture the controller events using xev and report back.